# Yii - Using two main layouts for desktop and mobile

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, themes, yii

I'm developing a simple app that will be used by desktops and mobile.

I'm trying to use this approach:

Before rendering the main action in the main controller I'm checking if the brower belongs to a "mobile" category (Using the plugin detecmobilebrowser [detecmobilebrowser](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/detectmobilebrowser/)) then I need to switch to another flow (The actions available will be different) and for this actions I'll use a layout developed with jquery mobile to ensure the compatibility to different devices.

Using a:

```
$this->layout='//layouts/mobile';
```

changes the layout, but renders first main.php.

Is there a way to solve this without creating a new theme?

Thanks for your support

Comment: where did you put that line of code?

Comment: and have you checked your mobile layout file? is it completely correct, check if you have by mistake included the main.php layout in mobile.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was changing the layout and the action at the same time in a new controller. I works fine!